# Convert B4A layout to XML version

Tags: xml, vb4android

Is there anyway to convert B4A designed layouts (.bal) to XML version? I am making layouts in B4A designing tool but i want to have 'em in XML too.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert bal file to xml but can use xml layout file in B4a with XmlLayoutBuilder

You can convert to bil file(B4i layout) also